# Stacked Bar Chart is not working properly using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot 100% stacked bar chart but i am getting wrong output.
The aligned and the percentages are all messed up.

[image: 100% Stacked Bar Chart]

```
x = ["A","B","C","D"]
data1 = {'Price':[12,44,23,21]}
data2 = {'Cost':[15,40,10,15]}
data3 = {'Units':[22,12,23,15]}
y1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
y2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
y3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)
snum = y1['Price']+y2['Cost']+y3['Units']

y11 = y1['Price']/snum*100
y22 = y2['Cost']/snum*100
y33 = y3['Units']/snum*100

plt.figure(figsize=(4,3))

# stack bars
plt.bar(x, y11, label='y1')
plt.bar(x, y22 ,bottom=y11 ,label='y2')
plt.bar(x, y33 ,bottom=y11+y22+y33,label='y3')

for xpos, ypos, yval in zip(x, y11/2, y11):
    plt.text(xpos, ypos, "%.1f"%yval, ha="center", va="center")
for xpos, ypos, yval in zip(x, y11+y22/2, y22):
    plt.text(xpos, ypos, "%.1f"%yval, ha="center", va="center")
for xpos, ypos, yval in zip(x, y11+y22+y33/2, y33):
    plt.text(xpos, ypos, "%.1f"%yval, ha="center", va="center")
```

Comment: Maybe replace `plt.bar(x, y33,bottom=y11+y22+y33,label='y3')` by `plt.bar(x, y33,bottom=y11+y22,label='y3')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By `bottom=y11+y22+y33`, the third bar will start at 100% and stick out. Just remove the `+y33` to get the desired result.

Here is the adapted code, also with slightly different colors. If you give the edge the same color as the bar, you avoid some possible white line between them.(I also imported the libraries and added `show()`.)

```py
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = ["A","B","C","D"]
data1 = {'Price':[12,44,23,21]}
data2 = {'Cost':[15,40,10,15]}
data3 = {'Units':[22,12,23,15]}
y1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
y2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
y3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)
snum = y1['Price']+y2['Cost']+y3['Units']

y11 = y1['Price']/snum*100
y22 = y2['Cost']/snum*100
y33 = y3['Units']/snum*100

plt.figure(figsize=(4,3))

# stack bars
plt.bar(x, y11, label='y1', color='#fbb4ae', edgecolor='#fbb4ae')
plt.bar(x, y22, bottom=y11, label='y2', color='#b3cde3', edgecolor='#b3cde3')
plt.bar(x, y33, bottom=y11+y22, label='y3', color='#ccebc5', edgecolor='#ccebc5')

for xpos, ypos, yval in zip(x, y11/2, y11):
    plt.text(xpos, ypos, "%.1f"%yval, ha="center", va="center")
for xpos, ypos, yval in zip(x, y11+y22/2, y22):
    plt.text(xpos, ypos, "%.1f"%yval, ha="center", va="center")
for xpos, ypos, yval in zip(x, y11+y22+y33/2, y33):
    plt.text(xpos, ypos, "%.1f"%yval, ha="center", va="center")

plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Edit: setting edgecolor to prevent white lines between bars.